Combining ArcMap style files into one file
Over the years of using ArcMap and across the 10.x versions I have saved many styles in my xx.style file. Now I have many styles files stacked in my PC and it has been very annoying to manage them all with the style manager.
Is there is a way to combine them all in one file??


I'm not aware of any import or merge tool for combining style files.
What you can do is copy from one to another, which I show in the video below. You could bring your styles into a single style file.
Click on video to enlarge.


thanks a lot that actually  works
